# Dynamic props in component tag with Vue tab

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a question which I cannot solve by my self.

I want to create a simple news portal app with Laravel and Vue (SPA)

I have a Home / Index component with many tabs (Vue tabs)

In each of these tabs, I want to display different news based on their category
Like health, technology, gaming, etc

So in my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button"
            v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab"
            @click="changeTab(tab)"
        >{{ tab }}</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <component :is="currentTab"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Health from '...'
    import Technology from '...'
    import Gaming from '...'
    import ...
    import ...

    export default {
        components: {
            Health,
            Technology,
            Gaming,
            ...
        },
        data() {
            return {
                currentTab: 'Health', // Starting point, (when user visit the index)
                tabs: [
                    'Health',
                    'Technology',
                    'Gaming',
                    ....
                ],
                health: [
                    // object, title, image, etc, source
                ],
                technology: [
                    // object, title, image, etc, source
                ],
                ...
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeTab(val) {
                this.currentTab = val
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to pass the data from this component to health, tech, gaming component using props (or perhaps any other way to pass them)?

```
<component :is="currentTab"></component>
// Idk how to pass them within this component tag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what structure these components expect their props in, I would suggest an approach like this:

```
    <component
        :is="currentTab"
        v-bind="currentProps"
    />

    ...

    computed: {
        currentProps() {
            return this[this.currentTab.toLowerCase()];
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, your answer is working as I expected, I forgot to mention that each child component using props: data

Comment: so in my child component would be like this:  `props: ['data']`